# How to compare values of an array alphabeticaly in ruby? (without .sort)

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

As part of an exercise, I'm supposed to compare elements of an array and sort them without using .sort. There is a lot about this on the web, but I couldn't find an answer to this particular concern:

```
words =  [ 'a', 'b']

if words.at(0).to_s > words.at(1).to_s
    puts true
else
    puts false
end
```

The terminal outputs:

```
$irb > false
```

My question: how is **a** not greater than **b**?
(this is driving me crazy, I've tried many variations of this code...)

Comment: Why do you expect a to be greater than b? Intuitively, b is greater than a and that's how it is in Ruby.

Comment: `a` comes before `b`, therefore it's 'less than' `b`. Makes sense to me...

Comment: @MarekLipka perhaps it is not "intuitively" greater, but this choice of ordering does give the intuitive result `%w{b c a}.sort => ["a", "b", "c"]` since Ruby sorts from least to greatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how is a not greater than b?

It isn't, by convention based on the English/Latin alphabet, and how those letters are represented in Ruby strings. The letter 'a' is less than 'b', and this is the same on all the computer languages and systems I can think of.

This is also consistent with 1 being less than 2, assuming characters are counted/scored by their typical position in the English alphabet. Which happens to be how computers represent them in ASCII code (where 'a' is represented by 97 and 'b' by 98).

If you need/expect your test between 'a' and 'b' to return `true` for your sort algorithm to work, just reverse the `>` into a `<`, or switch the `0` and `1` indexes to get the correct logic.

More interesting (or annoying) comparisons can happen due to poor support for accented characters on early computer systems, and the character codes for them are not always the most useful for sorting. E.g. `'À' > 'Z' # => true`

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to expect a to be greater than b. Intuitively, b is greater than a and that's how it is in Ruby. BTW, your code can be much shorter:

```
words = %w(a b)
puts words[0] > words[1]
```

Comment: or `words[0] > words[1]`